# D3: How to update a line chart when selecting from a drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Let's assume I have the following data:

```
Year      Teams     Matches    Goals
2014      32        64         171
2010      32        64         125
2006      32        64         147
2002      32        64         161
1998      32        64         171
1994      24        52         141
```

I'm trying to create a line plot with data from ***either*** `Teams`, `Matches`, or `Goals` (based on which of these the user selects from a drop-down menu).

Here is my code:

`index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Line Chart</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="row">

    <div class="row">
        <div id="line-plot-user-selection">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="metric-type" onchange="updateMetric()">
                    <option value="Teams">Number of Teams</option>
                    <option value="Matches">Number of Matches</option>
                    <option value="Goals" selected>Number of Goals</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="line-plot-div">

    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

In `main.js`:

```
let promises = [
    d3.csv('data/world-cup-data.csv', d3.autoType),
];

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function (data) {
        createVis(data)
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });


function createVis(data) {

    let lineChartData = data[0]

    // Instantiate the visualizations
    lineChart = new LineChart('line-plot-div', lineChartData, 'Test Title');

}




let metricType = document.getElementById('metric-type').value;

function updateMetric() {

    metricType = document.getElementById('metric-type').value;

    lineChart.wrangleData();

}
```

Then, in `lineChart.js`:

```
class LineChart {

    constructor(parentElement, data, chartTitle) {
        this.parentElement = parentElement;
        this.data = data;
        this.chartTitle = chartTitle;

        this.initVis()
    }

    initVis() {

        let vis = this;

        vis.metricType = 'Teams';

        vis.margin = {top: 80, right: 90, bottom: 90, left: 80};
        vis.width = 800 - vis.margin.left - vis.margin.right;
        vis.height = 700 - vis.margin.top - vis.margin.bottom;

        // initialize the drawing area
        vis.svg = d3.select('#' + vis.parentElement).append('svg')
            .attr('width', vis.width + vis.margin.left + vis.margin.right)
            .attr('height', vis.height + vis.margin.top + vis.margin.bottom)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate (${vis.margin.left}, ${vis.margin.top})`);


        // scales and axes
        vis.xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range( [ 0, vis.width ] );

        vis.yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range( [ vis.height, 0 ] );

        vis.xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
            .scale(vis.xScale);

        vis.yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
            .scale(vis.yScale);

        // add chart title
        vis.svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'title line-chart-title')
            .append('text')
            .text(vis.chartTitle)
            .attr('transform', `translate(${vis.width / 2 + 45}, -30)`)
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');


        // create the axis groups
        vis.xAxisGroup = vis.svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'x-axis axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + vis.height + ')');

        vis.yAxisGroup = vis.svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'y-axis axis');


        // create axis labels

        // vertical axis
        vis.svg.append('text')
            .attr('x', -65)
            .attr('y', -20)
            .text('Count')
            .style('font-size', 20)
            .style('font-weight', 600)
            .style('fill', 'blue');

        // horizontal axis
        vis.svg.append('text')
            .attr('x', vis.width - 35)
            .attr('y', vis.height + 50)
            .text('Year')
            .style('font-size', 20)
            .style('font-weight', 600)
            .style('fill', 'blue');

        this.wrangleData()

    }

    wrangleData() {

        let vis = this;

        let filteredData = []

        vis.metricType = metricType;

        filteredData = vis.data


        vis.updateVis()

    }

    updateVis() {

        let vis = this;

        // update the domains
        vis.xScale.domain([ d3.min(vis.data, function(d) {return d.Year; }), d3.max(vis.data, function(d) {return d.Year }) ]);
        vis.yScale.domain( [ 0, d3.max(vis.data, function(d) {return d[vis.metricType]; }) ] );

        // draw the line
        vis.line = vis.svg.selectAll('.line')
            .data(vis.data)

        vis.line.exit().remove();

        // draw the line
        vis.line
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('class', 'line')
            .merge(vis.line)
            .datum(vis.data)
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr('d', d3.line()
                .x(function (d) { return vis.xScale(d.Year); })
                .y(function (d) { return vis.yScale(d[vis.metricType]); })
                .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
            );


        // add the axes
        vis.xAxisGroup
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style('font-size', '15px')
            .style('color', 'blue')
            .call(d3.axisBottom((vis.xScale)).tickFormat(d3.format('')))
            .selectAll('text')
            .attr('y', 20)
            .attr('x', 0)
            .attr('dy', '.35em')

        ;

        vis.yAxisGroup
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style('font-size', '15px')
            .style('color', 'blue')
            .call(d3.axisLeft(vis.yScale));

    }

}
```

Currently, the line chart for `Teams` is displaying properly.  But, when I select `Matches` or `Goals` from the drop-down menu, the line does not update.  It remains static and only displays the data for `Teams`.

I believe the problem is in `wrangleData()`.  It's not grabbing the user's section and applying the filter.

Can someone help me understand how to fix my code so that the line draws when `Matches` or `Goals`  is selected by the user?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen your question

i'm a bit confusing why are you making so complicated by using class and constructor for updating graph.. ok anywhay

so i have just made a simple functional graph with dropdown you can see on this live code but i did not used your core graph code, i made the simple functional graph with all futures like `tooltip` `gridlines` and `transition` etc
If you dont mind you can chage the design according to your needs. that i'm pasting the codepan source code link too

**here is the graph**

```js
const convertRemToPixels = (rem) => {
  return rem * parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
};
const dt = [
  { year: "2014", value: 35 },
  { year: "2010", value: 32 },
  { year: "2006", value: 32 },
  { year: "2002", value: 34 },
  { year: "1998", value: 25 },
  { year: "1994", value: 32 },
];
const margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const update = (data) => {
  const svg = d3
    .select("#mainChart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .select("#mainGroup")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

  let tooltip = d3
    .select("#tooltipContainer")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("top", 0)
    .style("left", 0)
    .style("display", "none");

  // grid function
  function make_y_gridlines() {
    return d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(6);
  }

  // Add X axis --> it is a date format
  const x = d3.scalePoint().range([0, width]);

  const y = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data.map((e) => parseInt(e.value)))])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(6);
  x.domain(
    data.map(function (d) {
      console.log(d);
      return d.year;
    })
  ).padding([0.2]);
  svg
    .select("#XAxis")
    .transition()
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .style("color", "#a4a4a4");

  svg
    .select("#XAxis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", ".6em")
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("font-size", ".8rem")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
    .style("font-family", '"Roboto", sans-serif');

  // Add Y axis

  svg
    .select("#YAxis")
    .transition()
    .call(yAxis)
    .style("color", "#a4a4a4")
    .style("font-size", ".7rem");

  svg
    .select("#linePath")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#14c884")
    .transition()
    .attr(
      "d",
      d3
        .line()
        .x(function (d) {
          console.log(d);
          return x(d.year);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
          return y(d.value);
        })
        .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(1.1))
    );
  const circle = d3.select("#LineDots");

  circle
    .selectAll(".point")
    .data(data)
    .join("circle")
    .on("mouseover", (e, i) => {
      d3.select(e.target).transition().attr("r", 4);

      tooltip.transition().duration(0).style("display", "block");
      tooltip
        .html(`<div>${i.year} : <span>${i.value}</span></div>`)
        .style("left", e.pageX + convertRemToPixels(-1.6) + "px")
        .style("top", e.pageY - convertRemToPixels(2) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", (e) => {
      d3.select(e.target).transition().attr("r", 2);

      tooltip.transition().duration(0);
      tooltip.style("left", "0px").style("top", "0px").style("display", "none");
    })
    .transition()
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("stroke", "#14c884")
    .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
      return "#14c884";
    })
    .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
      return x(d.year);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d, i) {
      return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("r", function (d, i) {
      return 2;
    })
    .style("opacity", 1);
  d3.select("#Grid")
    .transition()
    .call(make_y_gridlines().tickSize(-width).tickFormat(""))
    .attr("id", "gridSystem");
};

update(dt);
const selectGroupFromDropDown = document.getElementById("metric-type");

selectGroupFromDropDown.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  
  if(e.target.value === "Matches"){
    data = [
    { year: "2014", value: 64 },
    { year: "2010", value: 64 },
    { year: "2006", value: 64 },
    { year: "2002", value: 64 },
    { year: "1998", value: 64 },
    { year: "1994", value: 52 },
  ];
  update(data);
}else if(e.target.value === "Goals"){
  data = [
    { year: "2014", value: 171 },
    { year: "2010", value: 125 },
    { year: "2006", value: 149 },
    { year: "2002", value: 161 },
    { year: "1998", value: 171 },
    { year: "1994", value: 141 },
  ];
  update(data);
}else if(e.target.value === "Teams"){
  const dt = [
  { year: "2014", value: 35 },
  { year: "2010", value: 32 },
  { year: "2006", value: 32 },
  { year: "2002", value: 34 },
  { year: "1998", value: 25 },
  { year: "1994", value: 32 },
];
  update(dt)
}
});
```

```css
#gridSystem line{
        stroke: lightgrey;
        stroke-opacity: 0.7;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        stroke-dasharray: 2 2;
        stroke-width : .05rem ;
    }

   #gridSystem path {
        stroke-width: 0;
    }

/* tooltip */
.barTitle{
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: .2em 0;
  font-size: .8rem;
  color: black;
}
.tooltipContainer div span{
  color: #536876;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.bar{
  border-top-left-radius: 1em !important;
}

#tooltipContainer {
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .6em 1em .6em 1em;
    background:white;
   
    color: #9cb3c3;
    border-radius: .4em;
    font-weight: 600;
    box-shadow: 0em 0em .5em rgb(165, 163, 163);
    font-size: .6rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.1/d3.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="metric-type">
          <option value="Teams">Number ofTeams</option>
          <option value="Matches">Number of Matches</option>
          <option value="Goals" selected>Number of Goals</option>
</select>


<div id="tooltipContainer"></div>
  
   <svg id="mainChart">
        <g id="mainGroup">
          <g id="XAxis"></g>
          <g id="YAxis"></g>
          <g id="Grid"></g>
          <path id="linePath"></path>
          <g id="LineDots"></g>
        </g>
      </svg>
```

and here is the same source code from codepan

https://codepen.io/codingdarci/pen/LYrByKG

i hope this would solve your issue